# Афиша, автоматически сменяемая каждый год

Tags: wordpress, таймер

Здравствуйте! Создаю сайт на WordPress. Сделал баннер вида: "%такая-то акция% времени до конца акции и кнопка забронировать. Как на скрине [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Таймер использую T(-) Countdown (хотя и не принципиально именно его использовать). Текст - title таймера. Так вот вопрос:
Как можно реализовать автоматическую смену текста и отсчета времени на следующий таймер. Т.е. данная акция заканчивается 14 февраля в 22:00, появляется следующий таймер(например, "Пригласи своего мужа в ресторан на 23 февраля" и часики, разумеется).
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариантов реализации можно предложить сколько угодно. Можно написать скрипт на jQuery, можно на PHP, а так же можно связать с Wordpress - например, сделать кастомный тип записей и сделать привязку по времени. Это лишь идеи реализации, т.к. повторюсь, что сделать можно любыми средствами.

Я предложу простейший вариант на PHP:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Moscow');

$date = strtotime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s'));
$time = strtotime(date('Y').'-02-14 22:00:00'); // 14 февраля 22:00

if ( $date > $time ) {
    echo 'ПОСЛЕ указанной даты';
} else {
    echo 'ДО указанной даты';
}
?>
```

Comment: Вы - герой! Спасибо большое!!! А можно как-нибудь сделать, чтобы каждый год появлялась дата?

Comment: Я правильно понял вопрос на счет даты: 14 февраля в 22:00 каждый год?

Comment: Да, именно так
Т.е. чтобы не приходилось каждый год код менять, ведь праздники стоят на месте, а вот текст может измениться). С 30 декабря по 1 февраля один таймер с текстом, с 1 февраля по 14 - другой и так далее

Comment: Конечно можно. Заменил 2018 на текущий год date('Y')

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Я на самом деле очень много времени голову ломал, как это реализовать.